# Mac App Store Application iTMSTransporter error

Tags: ios, command-line

I'm trying to send my pkg file to Apple, but the system says that the Transporter is searching for updated software components,and the process is always running,can't stop.
   Here's my activity log. Looks like an uploading error...?

I have installed the iTMSTransporter_1.7.7.pkg and I have add a TRANSPORTER_HOME environment.

I put this command in terminal in the directory where Transporter is installed.

```
   ./iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -u ......@gmail.com -p ...... -vendor_id testServer -destination /Users/tankMo/Downloads/videoPlayerTest.itmsp


[2013-10-08 21:04:09 CST] <main>  INFO: Transporter is searching for updated software components.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main>  INFO: Transporter has detected that new software components exist; updating.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.beanutils...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.cli...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.digester...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.discovery...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.io...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.commons.math...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.net...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.felix.bundlerepository...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.sanselan.sanselan...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.xml.resolver...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.asperasoft.faspmanager...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.transporter.asperasupport...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.transporter...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.transporter.updater...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.activation...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.media.jai.codec...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.mail...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.servlet...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.xml.soap...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.xml.rpc...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.xml.stream...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource jaxb.api-2.0.5...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.jaxen...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.jdom...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.json.simple...
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2013-10-08 21:04:48 CST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.jingle.leghorn...
```

So how should I close the update process now? the Transporter updating process never seem to end,was there a problem with this? Help me please,thanks a lot for any help with this issue.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, have you followed these steps: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: It is an Apple’s command-line tool used for sending App Store packages  to the App Store. I have checked the command and I tried google,but I couldn't find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Last login: Tue Oct 22 10:50:13 on ttys001
TangtekiMac-mini:~ tankLei$ iTMSTransporter -help
[2013-10-22 10:50:37 CST] <main>  INFO: Transporter is searching for updated software components.
[2013-10-22 10:51:04 CST] <main>  INFO: Transporter has detected that new software components exist; updating.
[2013-10-22 10:51:04 CST] <main> DEBUG: Another Transporter process is actively updating, pid 881; aborting update process.
usage: iTMSTransporter [-help <arg> | -info | -m <arg> | -version]   [-o <arg>] [-v
       <arg>]  [-WONoPause <arg>] [-Xmx1024m]
iTMSTransporter : iTunes Store Transporter 1.7.5.2
 -help <arg>        Show this help.  If a mode value is specified, show help specific
                    to that mode.
 -info              The -info option should be used by itself and returns the
                    copyright notice and acknowledgements.
 -m <arg>           The -m option specifies the tool's mode.  The valid values are:
                    verify, upload, provider, diagnostic, lookupMetadata, status,
                    statusAll, queryTickets, generateSchema, transferTest,
                    downloadMetadataGuides, iTunesExtraQCDownload, iTunesLPQCDownload,
                    iTunesExtraTemplate, iTunesLPTemplate
 -o <arg>           The -o option specifies the directory and filename you want to use
                    to log output information.  By default, Transporter logs output
                    information to standard out. If you specify a filename,
                    Transporter logs the output to the specified file, as well as to
                    standard out.
 -v <arg>           The -v option specifies the level of logging.  The five values
                    are: off, detailed, informational, critical, eXtreme.
 -version           The -version option should be used by itself and returns the
                    version of the tool.
 -WONoPause <arg>   The -WONoPause option is only valid on Windows and its value can
                    be 'true' or 'false'.  If an error occurs during script execution,
                    the process idles because the message 'Press any key...' is
                    displayed on the console and the system awaits a keypress. To
                    avoid this behavior, set this property to true
 -Xmx1024m          Specifies that you want to change the Java Virtual Machine's (JVM)
                    allocated memory by increasing the JVM heap size.  By default,
                    Transporter uses a 512MB heap size. You can use the -Xmx1024m
                    option to specify a 1-gigabyte (GB) heap size. Apple recommends,
                    if needed, increasing the heap size to 1024MB by specifying the
                    -Xmx1024 option and adjusting as needed.
TangtekiMac-mini:~ tankLei$
```

Answer (score 1):

In typical Apple fashion, Transporter will *always* try to update itself. I think this is even the case when running `iTMSTransporter -help` :(  After it updates itself your command will automatically start.

I think I tried hacking around with the Transporter jar and `~/.itmstransporter` directory looking for a way to disable this but had no luck. (You might want see what's in `~/.itmstransporter`, but don't get your hopes up...)

Comment: Thanks.I have solved this problem.I find an approach that when Transporter update itself I open another terminal,give myself sudo privleges to run iTMSTransporter -help or iTMSTransporter -m......

Comment: You can also use the following without sudo privleges.I find that it must run in another terminal.