# iTMSTransporter software update issue

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, itmstransporter

I am writing a custom solution to create & upload iOS apps to app store using the  `iTMSTransporter`. Whenever it starts, it checks for the software updates from apple. God, this is the frustrating tool i have ever used. Every day it checks for the updates, and it runs endlessly, and always struck at this line

> [2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST]  DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle
>   resource com.apple.jingle.leghorn...

I dont know what it downloads, it pauses here for hours. I have to kill it to use the iTMSTransporter again. Sometimes it goes again to updating the software components. If i am lucky, it stops at some time and do the work it supposed to do.

This is happening all the time irrespective of the commands i am supplying. Even `--help` is updating the damn software components every time.

THis is the full log

```
mPub|development ✗⇒ iTMSTransporter -u apple@myusername.com -p mypass -v off -m  lookupMetadata -vendor_id 46saTYYTG  -destination /tmp/46saTYYTG
[2014-04-25 16:51:03 IST] <main>  INFO: Transporter is searching for updated software components.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main>  INFO: Transporter has detected that new software components exist; updating.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.beanutils...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.codec...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.cli...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.digester...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.discovery...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.io...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.commons.math...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.commons.net...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.felix.bundlerepository...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.apache.sanselan.sanselan...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.apache.xml.resolver...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.asperasoft.faspmanager...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.transporter.asperasupport...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.transporter...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.transporter.updater...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... updated bundle already exists in download folder.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.activation...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.media.jai.codec...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.mail...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.servlet...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.xml.soap...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.xml.rpc...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.javax.xml.stream...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource jaxb.api-2.0.5...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.jaxen...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.springsource.org.jdom...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource org.json.simple...
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG:   ... resource is same as system bundle, skipping download.
[2014-04-25 16:51:13 IST] <main> DEBUG: Analyzing remote bundle resource com.apple.jingle.leghorn...
```

can someone help me how to fix this or workaround this software update issue. We have huge automated app distribution queue. It disastrously fails because of this stupid sick issue. I have been battling this for last 2 weeks. Not able to find or workaround any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to hack around this a few years ago; no luck.

@tankLei found [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249188/mac-app-store-application-itmstransporter-error/19286963#comment28939071_19286963). Essentially he/she runs an instance of `iTMSTransporter` to do the update, then runs a second, which sees that the update is taking place and skips it.

How long have you waited for? Do you have a reasonable amount of bandwidth while this is going on?

Comment: thanks @sshaw. Seems its a nice trick. i ll try out & let you know

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue, think I have found the solution.
If you only use it to download (Lookup Mode) the data from iTunes Connect, each time you run it, it will have the same update process. But after a successful upload using the Upload Mode, you won't get that checking again, you will get "INFO: Transporter is skipping bundle update check: Already checked recently." rather than the lengthy updates. Hope this helps.